# Mouse programming in c

Tags: c, mouse, turbo-c

I am working on my minor project. I have to create an image editor in C. For that I want to handle mouse. As I know there are two approaches to handle mouse viz REQUEST MODE and EVENT MODE.

Over the past few days I have learnt Request mode but I'm having difficulty in performing a couple of things with request mode, so I decided to learn second approach i e Event mode. But unfortunately I can't find proper resources. It would be very nice of you if you can get me some examples and explanation of event mode approach.

Comment: You've written a lot of words, but nothing that we can use to help you. First, which operating system are you using? What have you done so far? (Show us the code.)

Comment: i'm sorry, I am using Widnows Xp with turbo c compiler. Actually i am having trouble in drawing a rectangle by draging mouse with left click like ms-paint

Comment: Turbo C is a DOS compiler. Download [Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) instead (it's free) and use that. Turbo C is at least 20 years old and you won't learn anything useful from it.

Comment: @greg on the other hand the ms C compiler only support a 23 year old C standard

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i dont think i am not supposed to build my project in visual c++, i have to deal with turbo c only

Comment: A lot of schools and universities still teach beginner programming classes in Turbo Pascal or Turbo C. That is why you are not allowed to use newer compilers?

Comment: Well, good luck with that. Nobody remembers how to access DOS mouse drivers.

Comment: Maybe the PC Game Programming Encyclopedia has something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this site

http://www3.telus.net/alexander_russell/course/introduction.htm

its a dos game programming site

there is a mouse section at chapter 4